# same img size in a row /// col-8 <-> col-4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am absolute newbee and wanna create 2 rows. One with 2 img col-4 size and col-8 size and the other row à 3 x col-4 size.
My problem is that the col-8 img is a little bit bigger (height) then the col-4 img.
How can I fix it? I tried a lot but nothing worked.
Thanks for your help.
[problem

```css
.col-4 {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.col-8 {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.x1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.x2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.x1_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.x2_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.x1_header {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -95%;
  text-align: center;
}

.x2_header {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -95%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="x1">
                <img class="x1_pic" src="./img/header-background.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="x2">
                <img class="x2_pic" src="./img/maschine_2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="x1">
                <img class="x1_pic" src="./img/header-background.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="x1">
                <img class="x1_pic" src="./img/header-background.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="x1">
                <img class="x1_pic" src="./img/header-background.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BBNz.jpg)

Comment: why not use bootstraps classes for img `class="img img-responsive` should work as you expect

Comment: Restrict the size of your images.